# how to add space between textbox and browse button for input file type

Tags: html

Can we add space between the browse button and textbox for input type file ?Is that possible? Aslo can i add border color for the same  textbox ?

thanks,

michaeld

Answer (score 4):

Increasing spacing is not possible. Generally speaking, styling an `input type="file"` is extremely difficult. If you check cross-browser, you can see that different browsers render it differently. The only way to style it is to fake another element as `input type="file"`

Example: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 1):

add margin right to the input button

```
// using css
<style>
input[type="file"]::file-selector-button {
    margin-right: 4px;
}
</style>

// using tailwind
<input type="file" class="file:mr-4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use css to do this:
Your html:

```
    <input type="text" class="yourclass" name="yourname" />
    <input type="submit" />
```

your css:

```
    <style> input.yourclass { border:1px solid red; margin-right: 10px;} </style>
```

Hope this puts you in the right direction

Comment: my question is for <input type="file">

Answer (score -1):

It is working for me in Chrome.

```
input.file {
    text-indent: initial;
}
```